# Error Message on Main Activity: 'illegal start of expression'

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build a simple application where if a user inputs a text message and clicks a button, the message shows on the next view.

It used to work fine, but then I added some lines of code, and deleted it back, and now it does not work again as it used to.

The complier won't run my code, and keep saying 'illegal start of expression' and '; expected'.

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out here.
Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.yhmac.myapplication3.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroToApp.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please close your onCreate method.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.yhmac.myapplication3.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroToApp.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will work.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}    

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroToApp.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How did you know `sendMessage()` defined under `onCreate()`? `sendMessage()` might be an direct `onClick()` event

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.yhmac.myapplication3.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroToApp.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```