# onActivity gives me weird errors

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have this code on MainActivity and I keep on getting the errors illegal start of expression, error ";" expected and  expected on my OnActivitys parameters how would you fix this. I'm going after this tutorial on Room and views on codelabs https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#13 but eaven if I copy paste it in to the editor it still gives me a fault. please help and Thanks in advance. I have also checked this one for help still not working though [Error Message on Main Activity: 'illegal start of expression'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602133/error-message-on-main-activity-illegal-start-of-expression)

```
package com.example.jenso.paperseller;

import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomerDatabase database;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    private CustomerViewModel mCustomerViewModel;


    public static final int NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;



    private static final  String TAG = "MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        final PapperRecyclerAdapter adapter = new PapperRecyclerAdapter(this);


        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mCustomerViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CustomerViewModel.class);

        mCustomerViewModel.getmAllCustomers().observe(this, new Observer<List<Customer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Customer> customers) {
                adapter.setCustomer(customers);
            }
        });



        public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Customer customer = new Customer(data.getStringExtra(CreateCustomer.EXTRA_REPLY), data.getStringExtra(CreateCustomer.SECOND_REPLY),data.getStringExtra(CreateCustomer.THIRD_REPLY),data.getStringExtra(CreateCustomer.FOURTH_REPLY));
                mCustomerViewModel.insert(customer);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.empty_not_saved,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateCustomer.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);


            }

        });









        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
















    }







}
```

Comment: You forgot `}` before `public void onActivityResult`

Comment: The use of "}", ";" and ")" can be very tricky when you implement a listener with .setOnWhateverListener. You must've forgotten a "}" as Eselfar said.

Comment: It fixed it thanks sadly comments are not available to give feedback on except in text but atleast I can say thx here